# Can't install ANY KDE Themes

Tags: themes, kde

I've been trying to install themes for KDE for quite a while now, but nothing works.

This is what I've tried so far --

- Going to System Settings / Desktop theme and hitting get new looks, then installing something does not work -- nothing is installed.
- The ~/.kde/share/apps/desktoptheme folder does not exist.
- Clicking the install button next to any theme on https://store.kde.org/ simply brings up an error message.

If anyone knows how to fix this, that'd be awesome.

Three more quick questions I have if anyone can answer them:

- How to disable mouse pad in favor of a physical mouse? (I have a laptop)
- Do you know any good KDE themes that make it look like OS X? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks the directories changed from `~/.kde/share/apps/desktoptheme`
to `~/.local/share/plasma/desktoptheme/`. Icons should be stored in `~/.local/share/icons` and color-schemes in `~/.local/share/color-schemes/`